# How to overcoming skolemization problem in an assert expression

Tags: alloy

I have the following simple example.

```
sig B {}
pred P2 {some x1, x2: lone B | x1 != x2}
run P2 for 2
```

My question is how to rewrite the the pred constraint in an assert without getting skolemization error?

```
assert S { some x1, x2: lone B | x1 != x2} 
check S for 2
```

Comment: You might want to add your code that got the skolemization error

Comment: The assert constraint is the same as the predicate. <br/> assert S { some x1, x2: lone B | x1 != x2}

Comment: The problem is that I cannot just copy and paste the problem in Alloy and see what happens. I'll edit to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the extra quantifier lone in your assert solves the issue.

```
assert S { some x1, x2:  B | x1 != x2}
```

What would you like to assess ? I doubt using `lone B`  is what you intended to do.